# Share keyboard and mouse with Chrome OS

Tags: linux, mouse, keyboard, chrome-os

I've been using [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) for many years and I definitely like how it works.
But now I need to add a Chromebook to my list of devices and unfortunately Synergy does not support it.

I need to share both, the keyboard and mouse, between a Linux server and a Chrome OS client. Is there a similar application that can support Chrome OS.

Comment: Did you find any solution to share mouse and keyboards on ChromeOS?

Comment: you can run Linux apps in Chrome OS. Did you try that? Can Linux control the Chrome OS mouse?

Comment: @CarlosRamírez I couldn't find anything so I ended up using a USB switch. It's a little delayed and it can't share data (copy/paste) between devices, but it does the trick for now.